# Show route and map icon by default - Mapfragment Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, mapfragment

[image]

Hi,
1. Please find the route and map icon in the highlighted area.
2. These are shown on touch of the my location blue circle .
3. want to show those icons by default, without the user touching, as soon as the map loads.

Below is the code :

```
 protected void loadMap(GoogleMap googleMap, String latlng) {
        if (googleMap != null) {
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            String[] latlngAry = latlng.split(",");
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(latlngAry[0]);
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(latlngAry[1]);
            LatLng latlong = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            BitmapDescriptor defaultMarker =
                    BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE);

            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latlong)
                    .title("My Location")
                    .icon(defaultMarker));


            marker.showInfoWindow();
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlong, 18));  }
```

Comment: You can Accept My answer Because it is an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2):

The overlay that appears when a marker is clicked, is created and destroyed on-the-spot implicitly. You can't manually show that (yet).

If you must have this functionality, you can create an overlay over your map with 2 ImageViews, and call appropriate intents when they're clicked:

```
// Directions
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
        "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=51.5, 0.125&daddr=51.5, 0.15"));
startActivity(intent);
// Default google map
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
        "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:51.5, 0.125"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Note: you need to change the coordinates based on Marker's getPosition() and the user's location.

Now to hide the default overlay, all you need to do is return true in the OnMarkerClickListener. Although you loose the ability to show InfoWindows and center camera on the marker, you can imitate that simply enough:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker.getPosition()));
        return true;
    }
});
```